# To retrieve list data from sharepoint

Tags: javascript

I wanted to acces list data from sharepoint as i want to use that data in another application.Can u tell me how do i connect with sharepoint? ...

Answer (score 1):

you need to either use SharePoint list services or BDC (business data catalog) to pull data from SharePoint. Read [this](http://weblog.vb-tech.com/nick/archive/2006/02/24/1453.aspx) for clues on list services. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms563661(office.12).aspx) is article from MSDN on BDC.

Comment: hey thanx for the answer,but actually ti think i have put the question wrong.I want to create a request object so that i can fetch data frm sharepoint server thrgh responseXML,so can u tell me how can i do so